# Unable to run package setup:

Tags: sublimetext2

Getting this error in `sublime` text, wondering what to do about it. Is there a way to completely uninstall any related files to ST2? I tried uninstalling it and re-installing it, but this error still persists. I imagine there are some temp files, or cached files that I need to remove, is there a way to clear those out?

```
Unable to run package setup:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/sublime-text-2/PackageSetup.py", line 165, in upgrade
    upgradePackage(pkg, pristinedir, datadir, backupdir)
  File "/usr/lib/sublime-text-2/PackageSetup.py", line 158, in upgradePackage
    os.path.join(backupdir, base), inhibitOverwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/sublime-text-2/PackageSetup.py", line 90, in upgradeArchive
    writeFile(fname, newar.read(f))
  File ".\zipfile.py", line 834, in read
  File ".\zipfile.py", line 857, in open
  File ".\zipfile.py", line 824, in getinfo
KeyError: "There is no item named u'nathos-sass-textmate-bundle-0e46064/Snippets/expression(\\u2026).tmSnippet' in the archive"
```

Comment: Please provide details on what OS you are using.

Comment: I'm running Linux, but I've also found a similar problem, coincidentally? with the SASS bundle.

Comment: I'd also faced the same fate but luckily changing the permission of `~/.config/Sublime Text2/` resolved my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**On Ubuntu:-**

I found this is a permission issue. Just change the permission to `777`

`sudo chmod 777 -R /home/user/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/[package name]`

Comment: `chmod 777` is always a bad idea! some files were created by something running as root (sudo), probably another poorly designed installer or script somewhere. The best solution is in the comments above... `sudo chown -R USERNAME /home/USERNAME/.config/sublime-text-2`

Answer (score 21):

execute

```
sudo sublime
```

for the first time

Comment: This solved my problem, but I had to execute with full path: > sudo /usr/bin/sublime-text-2

Comment: I had to do `sudo sublime-text'. Using Sublime Text 2.0.2

Answer (score 15):

**On Ubuntu:**

I tried Achu solution but it didn't work. My Sublime Text 2 started working after I changed the files owner to my user. You have to open Terminal (ctrl+alt+t) and type:

```
sudo chown -R [your user name here] /home/[your user name here]/.config/sublime-text-2/
```

So, for example, if your user is "john" you have to type:

```
sudo chown -R john /home/john/.config/sublime-text-2/
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, if your sublime data isn't that important and you need to use it NOW like I did, you can also delete the sublime-text-2 folder.

Comment: After trying to do this I get many of similar errors: 
chown: changing ownership of ‘/home/wolfgang/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Ruby/Marshal.dump(obj-file)-(Md).sublime-snippet’: Input/output error

Answer (score 9):

Similar to Victor's answer, but more specific, I deleted the single file `C:\Users\(Username)\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\ Installed Packages\Sass.sublime-package` and then Sublime Text 2 started up fine.

Comment: I think I have another version, mine was in the app folder: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Sublime Text 2.0.1`

Answer (score 2):

The last line says:

```
KeyError: "There is no item named u'nathos-sass-textmate-bundle-0e46064/Snippets/expression(\\u2026).tmSnippet' in the archive"
```

So search for that object recursively in files in the sublime text user data directory:

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/
grep -r  nathos-sass-textmate-bundle-d6d079e *
#Result# Binary file Installed Packages/Sass.sublime-package matches
```

Then delete the offending file:

```
rm -rf Installed\ Packages/Sass.sublime-package
```

Comment: Exactly the problem I had. Here is the updated version for those who have sass bundle on Mac OS: `rm -rf ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Installed\ Packages/Sass.sublime-package`

Answer (score 2):

I deleted some erronous packages which solved my problem. Steps to do it here: http://untroubler.com/questions/8-sublime-text-2-and-unable-to-run-package-setup

Update after comment below:

This is due to a corrupt install of a package. On OSX, goto: 
/Users/YOU_USER_NAME/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Installed Packages/.
Remove the package you tried to install and it should work again.

Comment: Please give more detail in your answer, not just a link. Otherwise the answer will become useless if the link is broken in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find all related files to this bundle and deleted them manually. I've noticed that if I miss a package from somewhere ST2 recreates some folders based on packages related to it, so it's not enough to delete some folders, you have to really find all related data and delete it.

Comment: For Mac we have apps like [AppZapper](http://www.appzapper.com/) and [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) which do a great job of locating and removing all related files for an App. I was trying to locate a Linux version or similar software for Linux for you, but I came up empty unfortunately. Not even [alternativeTo](http://alternativeto.net/software/appzapper/) had anything listed.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo sublime-text`

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply reverting Sublime Text to a [freshly installed state](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/revert.html) resolved this issue.

Sublime Text 2 can be reverted to a freshly installed state by removing your data folder. Depending on your operating system, this folder is located:

- OS X: ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2
- Windows: %APPDATA%\Sublime Text 2
- Linux: ~/.config/sublime-text-2

To revert to a frestly installed state on Ubuntu 13.10, you can:

1. Exit Sublime Text 2
2. Delete (or move) the data folder, so running `sudo rm -rf
   ~/.config/sublime-text-2`
3. Start Sublime Text 2

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's already an answer related to permissions for Linux, but I found the issue was related to permissions for a Windows install. I placed the install for portable files into "Program Files/SublimeText2" - apparently when I run ST2 it needs additional permissions which it wasn't getting.

So I installed ST2 portable to a folder in a user directory (e.g. A folder my user created and maintains - C:\dev\SublimeText2) and everything works fine now.